# What is the original source for Yahrtzeit customs?

Tags: sources-mekorot, minhag, calendar, chazzan-prayer-leader, yahrtzeit

There are various customs and even halachot associated with yahrtzeits, such as saying kaddish, getting called to Torah, lighting candles, fasting, serving as a prayer leader, giving charity, arranging a minyan at the cemetery, etc. What is the earliest or most authoritative source for any of these customs/halachot?

Comment: This seems like two distinct questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Nitei Gavriel Aveilus2 75:1:1](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46540&st=&pgnum=560) brings the following sources for Yarzheit candles.

Minhagei Vermaisha Volume 2, Page 112

Maharshal Chapter 46

Magen Avraham 261:6

Nachalas Shiva Chapter 73

Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 221:1

Mishmeres Shalom Note 10:10

Gesher HaChaim 32:4

Will try to add more customs and sources later.

Comment: If you added the dates of these sources, it would be easier to judge which is the "original source".

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok - You can edit and add dates if you want.